# Windows 10 Desktop PC cannot play Audio CD

Tags: windows, compact-disc, audio-cd

Recently, my Windows 10 Desktop PC can no longer play Audio CDs. The disc seems to be recognized as Audio CD and I can even browse the disc and see the tracks:

[image]

But I cannot play the CD using any software. Windows Media Player doesn't think that there is a CD. VLC just throws an error:

```
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'cdda:///D:\'. Check the log for details.
```

Log:

```
cdda error: could not read TOCHDR
cdda error: no audio tracks found
```

At the same time, I found that the Eject operation is not working.

[image]

This optical drive can read Data CD just fine. And it used to play Audio CD too. What could have gone wrong? The drive model is "PLDS DVD+-RW DU-8A5LH" if that matters.

Comment: Boot from a Linux live stick (for example Ubuntu) and try to play a music CD to rule out a hardware failure.

Comment: And if playback works on Linux, then use DISM and SFC to fix Windows.

Answer (score 0):

How about go into Device Manager and locate the optical drive. Right click on it and remove/uninstall it. Reboot Windows which will detect tgecdrive and re-install drivers.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I tried it. It didn't make a difference. But it is a reasonable suggestion. Not sure why someone down vote it.

Answer (score -1):

Try installing full version of Media Player Classic Home Cinema (MPC-HC) from https://codecguide.com/download_k-lite_codec_pack_full.htm and then try to open CD in that player from player's File option.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).